# How to check Page.Validate() on client side (JavaScript) in ASP.Net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, validation

I want to check page validation on client side, like `Page.Validate()` but it's a server side method. Is there any client side function which can work like `Page.Validate()` with JavaScript?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`Page_ClientValidate()` will work. It returns true if the page was valid and it works fine.

If you are using ASP.NET 2.0, pass the validation group name as a parameter.
E.g.

```
if(Page_ClientValidate("SomeValidationGroup"))
     alert('its valid');
```

Otherwise if there is no validation group `Page_ClientValidate("")` will handle it.
E.g.

```
if(Page_ClientValidate(""))
     alert('its valid');
```

Comment: This is the quick answer.  Tim's answer gives more detail if needed, just no examples.

Comment: Note though that the Page_ClientValidate() does not exist if there are no validators on the page. So make sure to always check if it's there.

Comment: In my case, using Page_ClientValidate() derailed the functionality set up by the back end. Instead of performing the validation it just always returned true and no other validation actions or submission steps occurred. To the user the form didn't change.

Answer (score 25):

There is a mini-clientside-validation API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside

[image]

and here are some functions to trigger validation on validators:

[image]